# error : couldn't find any package by regex gstreamer0.10-gconf

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo. I just recently installed the pocketsphinx package. When I try to run the sample robocup.launch file, I get an error saying gconfaudiosrc is no element. Hence when i try sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-gconf, I get the following error:

E: Unable to locate package gstreamer0.10-gconf

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer0.10-gconf'

Any sugesstions on what I could do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300007/error-:-couldn%27t-find-any-package-by-regex-gstreamer0.10-gconf/) by [nithu](https://answers.ros.org/users/36888/nithu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Weird, you can try:

```
sudo apt install  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

Does that work?

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nithu](https://answers.ros.org/users/36888/nithu/) on 2018-08-08**:
It says that gstreamer0.10-plugins-good is already the newest version. But my problem still persists

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-08-08**:
Weird, try download the deb file [from here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/sound/gstreamer0.10-gconf) and install it by:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**Comment by [nithu](https://answers.ros.org/users/36888/nithu/) on 2018-08-08**:
Eureka!!! That worked!! Thanks

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-08-08**:
Glad I could help!